# Why image do not color match when many Landsat images are mosaicked in ERDAS?

Tags: erdas-imagine

When I try to mosaic Landsat images in ERDAS I get as result image with discordance in colors.

I tried histogram matching but no success.

The images were captured between March and May.

Comment: LandSat scenes often don't colour match. You will need to colour balance the images before mosaicing. You should be able to contrast stretch to get them close and then apply the changes but true colour matching is a more involved process.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a tip, the urgency with which your Question is likely to be treated here is quite dependent on how much relevant detail you provide at the outset.  I would recommend using the edit button to include the precise steps you are using.

Comment: Erdas Mosaic Pro has done good job for me. I suppose you can get a short time trial license for free.

Comment: Thank you all, i already tried Mosaic Pro and i used also  Breakpoints and Piecewise contrast to stretch the contrast but every time i got the same result, do you have any other ideas and I'm sorry for disturbing you but this i a week I'm working on this with no progress